# Is RemoteIpAddress in ASP.NET Core always equivalent to ASP.NET 4.x's REMOTE_ADDR?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-standard

In .net core application I have:

```
public static string GetIp(this HttpContext context)
{
    return context.Connection.RemoteIpAddress?.ToString();
}
```

and I am trying to achieve same thing in old net framework application where I have

```
public static string GetIp(this HttpContextBase context)
{
       return context.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
}
```

is  `context.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"]` same as `context.Connection.RemoteIpAddress`? Can there be cases when they would not match?

Comment: Nitpick: Your method should be named `GetIP`, not `GetIp`, as `IP` (from "IP address") is a 2-letter initialization, not a 2-letter word (the fact that ASP.NET Core's property is called `RemoteIpAddress` is a bug that can't be fixed, unfortunately).

Comment: .NET Standard 2.0 is not concerned with web-servers - that's ASP.NET Core 2.0+ - I've edited your question title.